# is my anti xss function safe?

Tags: javascript, security, filter, xss

I have some javascript functions on my website, but I don't know if it is safe to use them.

here is my code :

```
// works like PHP's $_GET
function get(name){
    name=name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    regexS="[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    regex=new RegExp(regexS);
    results=regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(results==null)
        return '';
    return results[1];
}

// and here is my anti xss filter
var param = unescape(decodeURI(get("q")));
param = param.replace(/<(.*?)>/gi, "");
someElement.innerHTML = param;
```

Is it possible to bypass this filters?

Comment: This may work to one extent or another with JS but only to a point, overall anything client side, is far from fool proof or secure. With that I wouldn't rely 100% on any client side prevention. If your injecting get variables into the innerHTML of an element, then you want to be even more careful cause someone could easily inject code into your page, then use that code to inject more fun stuff onto your server..

Comment: I am going to say: no, it is *not* safe and just adds a false sense of security like "magic_quotes" did. The fundamental issue with a "filter" approach is that it fails to be the correct solution - the correct solution is to *safely apply data at the usage site*. That is, if innerHTML should not contain HTML, *HTML-encode* it at the usage site - but then *why* use innerHTML to begin with?

Comment: Here’s a counter example: `?q=<script%0A>alert('XSS')</script%0A>`.

Answer (score 3):

Do not try and find XSSes on the way into your application. Your program may transform the data internally in such a way that any filter you create is likely to be circumventable.

Instead, apply proper HTML encoding of data on the way *out* of your application. That way you avoid the vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you simulate multiline mode in your second last line like this:

```
param = param.replace(/<([\s\S]*?)>/gi, "");
```

your example code would be safe as it is. The biggest flaw in your example code is using `innerHTML` when you do not want to add HTML at all. So instead of using `innerHTML` and trying to filter out HTML you should use [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/document.createTextNode) and you will not have to worry about XSS anymore. So keep your `get` function if you like it, and use the parameter values like this (adapted from MDN):

```
var param = unescape(decodeURI(get("q")));
var text  = document.createTextNode(param);
document.getElementById(someElement).appendChild(newtext);
```

If you use jQuery, you can use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) function, which itself uses `createTextNode`.